# Show $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-\|Ax\|^2) d\mu(x)=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{|\det(A)|}$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, determinant

$A$ is a invertible $n \times n$ matrix. Show:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-\|Ax\|^2) d\mu(x)=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{|\det(A)|}$

Can someone give me a hint on how to show that?

Comment: Use a coordinate transformation $y=Ax$. I assume $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure? Do you already know the value of $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-\Vert x \Vert^2) d\mu(x)$?

Comment: @Zardo Could you go into this further? Is $x$ in this case $\in \mathbb{R}^n$? What happens to $d\mu(x)$?

Comment: How much do you know about the transformation theorem? I know many different variants of it.

Comment: We did it like this: If $f: V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is (lebesgue-)integrable, then $\int_V f \, d\mu = \int_U (f \cdot \phi) |\det D\phi| \, d\mu$ (and $U,V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: Then use it for $V= U = \mathbb{R}^n$, $\phi(x) = A^{-1}x$. You should get the integral I mentioned above.

Comment: And $f := \exp(-\Vert x \Vert^2)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24965/discussion-between-zardo-and-kaos).